# table-inside div, need some space between table

Tags: html, css

I have tried different styles but I could not reach a solution, 
I need to make it like: [image]

However my code produce the output like follows:
[image]

I would like to give some space( same color with background) however either table goes up or does not work at all.  I would be happy if someone can help .

here is my code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extension.css" />
```

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="jumbotron">

    <div class="white"> <table>
        <tr>
          <td class='magenta'></td>
          <td class='magenta'></td>

          <tr>
            <td class="yellow"></td>
            <td class="blue"></td>

            <tr>

              <td class="white"></td>
              <td class="white"></td>

      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="white"> <table>
        <tr>
          <td class='magenta'></td>
          <td class='magenta'></td>

          <tr>
            <td class="yellow"></td>
            <td class="blue"></td>

            <tr>
              <td class="white"></td>
              <td class=""></td>

      </table> </div> <br><br><br>

    <div class="white">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class=''></td>
          <td class='magenta'></td>

          <tr>
            <td class="yellow"></td>
            <td class="blue"></td>

            <tr>
              <td class="white"></td>
              <td class="red"></td>

      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="white">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class='magenta'></td>
          <td class="green"></td>

          <tr>
            <td class=""></td>
            <td class="blue"></td>

            <tr>
              <td class="red"></td>
              <td class="red"></td>


      </table>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

and CSS.  almost none of the display ttypes did work or  I am doing a fundamental mistake here

```
    .jumbotron {
  background: black;
 display:flex;
  height: 75vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

table {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;

}

td {

 border:1px solid black;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m6ucyryb/

Comment: Please update the expected output image.

Comment: @I.Ahmed like this one, after  every 2 tables I would like to give a break like this. https://imgur.com/EJagmDz

Comment: Please check the solution, hope its work for you.

Comment: You want line breaks where?

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for  helping @I.Ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirement, You should use two table. The following code will create a table in HTML. So you have to use 2 times in a code.

```
<table>
</table>
```

The requirement contains 3 table row for each table, the following code will create a row in page, so the following code is added three times for each table:

```
<tr>
</tr>
```

And each row contains 4 table data. The following code will create one table data, so under each table row, the following code is used four times.

```
<td class='magenta'></td>
```

I think you you need some spacing between them, it can be added like giving a margin to an div element:

```
<div class = "margin"></div>
```

The final solution will be as follows:

```css
table {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  
}
.margin {
  margin-top:5px;
}
td {
  
 border:1px solid black;
}
 
.red{
  
  background-color:red;
}

.yellow{
  
  background-color:yellow;
}
.green{
  
  background-color:green;
}
.blue{
  
  background-color:blue;
}
.white{
  
  background-color:white;
}
.magenta{
  
  background-color:magenta;
}
.cyan{
  
  background-color:cyan;
}

.black{

background-color : Black;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extension.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
              <td class='magenta'></td>
              <td class='magenta'></td>
              <td class='magenta'></td>
              <td class='magenta'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="yellow"></td>
              <td class="blue"></td>
              <td class="yellow"></td>
              <td class="blue"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="white"></td>
              <td class="white"></td>
              <td class="white"></td>
              <td class="white"></td>
            </tr>
       </table>
       <div class = "margin"></div>
       <table>
            <tr>
              <td class="white"></td>
              <td class='magenta'></td>
              <td class='magenta'></td>
              <td class="green"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td class="yellow"></td>
               <td class="blue"></td>
               <td class="white"></td>
               <td class="blue"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="white"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
            </tr>
     </table>    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer